# How to push the initial page resetting the pages stack?

Tags: angularjs, reset, onsen-ui

i'm using Onsen (v1.3.12) and Angular to develop my cross-platform app.
I added a button to go back to the home page of the app, so if users make some pop or some push of pages, when they hit on "Home" button they go back to initial page.
I use the following code:

```
$rootScope.myNavigator.resetToPage('homepage.html');
```

but it doesn't show the animation effect of "popping page" that is visible with `pushPage` method.

To get this effect i have to use the following code:

```
$rootScope.myNavigator.pages.length = 1;
$rootScope.myNavigator.pushPage('splash.html');
$timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.myNavigator.pages.length = 0;
});
```

Isn't the default behaviour of `resetPage` method weird? Why it doesn't show the "pop" effect?

Answer (score 0):

I solved using `animation` option:

```
$rootScope.myNavigator.resetToPage('splash.html', {animation: 'slide'});
```

The weird thing is that `pushPage`, `popPage` and `resetPage` methods have default animation option set to `slide`. The same doesn't happen for `resetPage` method.

Maybe is a Onsen bug.

Comment: Hello! I don't know if the decision is correct or not, but `resetToPage` it's like that on purpose :)